# Get-Process with total memory usage

Tags: powershell

```
$Processes = get-process -computername $tag1 | Group-Object -Property ProcessName
foreach($Process in $Processes)
{
    $Obj = New-Object psobject
    $Obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Name -Value $Process.Name
    $Obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Mem -Value ($Process.Group|Measure-Object WorkingSet -Sum).Sum
    $Obj
}
```

Currently, this displays memory usage in bytes, how can I change this to show something like:

`76,592 KB`

and also output everything that is autosized? (aligned to the left)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Format-Table can show expressions and auto-size the columns to fit the results:

**On 64 bits:**

```
get-process -computername $tag1 | Group-Object -Property ProcessName | 
    Format-Table Name, @{n='Mem (KB)';e={'{0:N0}' -f (($_.Group|Measure-Object WorkingSet64 -Sum).Sum / 1KB)};a='right'} -AutoSize
```

**On 32 bits:**

```
get-process -computername $tag1 | Group-Object -Property ProcessName | 
    Format-Table Name, @{n='Mem (KB)';e={'{0:N0}' -f (($_.Group|Measure-Object WorkingSet -Sum).Sum / 1KB)};a='right'} -AutoSize
```

Comment: This works greatly. Thanks. Is there a way to add commas for the digits?

Comment: @Aaron for the comma portion you just need to have the output of the number into a format operation `'{0:N}' -f (($_.Group ... / 1KB})`

Comment: Can you be a little more specific on where to enter that?

Comment: @Aaron see my edit. IMO this actually makes the results harder to read because the column will be left justified instead of right justified.

Comment: @Aaron Actually, you can change the alignment with a key value pair, a="right", which I added as well.

Comment: Works, it makes every number like: 45,996.00 - any way to remove the .00 or is that the way it is?

Comment: @Aaron what you are supposed to be able to do is set the decimal places like this `{0:N0}`. The second 0 is for 0 decimal places. 
`{0:N2}` would be for 2 decimal places. For some reason it is ignoring this when i was testing. Might just have to use `[math]::round(...)` on the whole portion after `-f`

Comment: @mikez How to output this and convert to JSON?
Current output is quite different when using ConvertTo-Json

Comment: How to sort that output by totals per group process? I tried with placing sort before format but it sort only per single process and I want sort by totals per process.

Comment: @mike In that case it would be best use the Add-Member to attach a script property. Then you can reference that in Sort-Object and Format-Table like this: `| Group-Object -Property ProcessName | Add-Member -PassThru -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name "TotalMemory"
 -Value { ($this.Group | Measure-Object WorkingSet64 -Sum).Sum / 1KB } | Sort-Object TotalMemory | Format-Table Name, TotalMemory`

Answer (score 11):

```
Get-Process | Select-Object Name,@{Name='WorkingSet';Expression={($_.WorkingSet/1KB)}}
```

Answer (score 9):

To get the amount of memory per process used on a 64 bit windows operating system, run the following command...

```
 Get-Process | Sort-Object WorkingSet64 | Select-Object Name,@{Name='WorkingSet';Expression={($_.WorkingSet64/1KB)}} | Export-Csv -Path "processes64.csv" -Delimiter ","
```

Answer (score 8):

Just divide by 1KB

also can use 1MB, 1GB, 1TB.

Powershell is very helpful like that.

This link should help [Powershell Tip on Byte conversion](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692684.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

On 64bit systems:

```
get-process | Group-Object -Property ProcessName | 
% {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        ProcessName = $_.Name
        Mem_MB = [math]::Round(($_.Group|Measure-Object WorkingSet64 -Sum).Sum / 1MB, 0)
        ProcessCount = $_.Count
    }
} | sort -desc Mem_MB | Select-Object -First 25
```

On 32bit systems:

```
get-process | Group-Object -Property ProcessName | 
% {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        ProcessName = $_.Name
        Mem_MB = [math]::Round(($_.Group|Measure-Object WorkingSet -Sum).Sum / 1MB, 0)
        ProcessCount = $_.Count
    }
} | sort -desc Mem_MB | Select-Object -First 25
```