# Is there a way to programmatically check RAM usage of your program?

Tags: c++

I wrote a program that reads market tick data and splits the data into 10000 or so little files, one file per symbol. However it's way too slow, as I have 5 years of data to process and at this rate it will take too long. I have 500 ofstreams open at a time, and I am writing one message (1 to 5 lines) of data at a time. I think this is the bottleneck. I am only able to open 512 ofstreams at a time, so I have to run over the data 20 times or so.

So my idea is to store the split messages in strings and dump them to file once I hit ram max which I need a way to check programmatically. The files are between 10gb to 100gb depending how active the market was on the particular day and my system has 8gb of RAM.

Is what I'm planning doable? Is there a better way to do it?

Usecase: this data will only be read sequentially from beginning to end to replay a market simulation and test different trading strategies on the particular symbol/day.

Comment: The bottleneck is *probably* the hdd, and obviously your method of storage. Why not store the data in a database? Without altering your original program, you could essentially create a script to read files, store data in db and remove them.

Comment: Use database for archive data that is not being used every tick and tmpfs as a source for tick data. It is much faster than hdd. And in this case - your tmpfs volume consumption will show whan you need.

Answer (score 1):

An HDD is *much* more effective in writing 1 large file instead of 100 small ones because it can dump data right after each other in 1 single swipe of the needle. I'm assuming you're using a HDD because of the amount of data you're talking about is kind of costly when talking about an SSD which would probably prolong the issue you're having.

The reason it is becoming slower is because your operating system is having difficulty iterating over many files. A database is much more effective as it is 1 big file (actually a couple, but less than 10). The end result is that your "10gb" or "100gb" files is a *lot* smaller because it doesn't have to write headers and treat files seperatly as it will be 1 huge blob of data.

If you can alter your application, then store data in a database instead. If not than you can create a simple script that would iterate over each file, store the data in the proper columns and the delete the file.

Keep in mind that when the file is currently being written in, it will have an [`file lock`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking) in place. Check on that before you dump data into the database.

Storing the data in a database has advantages, all its data is accessible effortlessly.

Answer (score 0):

To check ram usage as title asks; I can across this not long ago:

[Get-Process with total memory usage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26552223/7641490)

Unfortunately that's the only way I can help.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question, if you are using Windows, there is no "memory usage" general counter for a process, but  the *"set of pages in the virtual address space of the process that are currently resident in physical memory".*

That is what is called the *Working set*.

The minimum and maximum working set of your process can be adjusted accordingly. Also, the current working set size can be obtained.

See the following Windows APIs:

GetProcessMemoryInfo: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683219(v=vs.85).aspx

To query and adjust working set limits:

GetProcessWorkingSetEx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683227(v=vs.85).aspx

SetProcessWorkingSetEx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686237(v=vs.85).aspx

For Linux systems, reading /proc/self/status will give you the same kind of information (which is called RSS: Resident Set Size). The RSS in the returned status is the 24th field.

Answer (score 0):

You can split a file in two passes provided that the number of pieces is (somewhat) less than the maximum number of open files (which is usually configurable, by the way, so you probably can do better than 500).

You need a reasonably good hash function. Now suppose you want to split it into *N* pieces using at most *n* simultaneously open files, and suppose that *N* is less than *n*². On the first pass, you open *n* temporary files, each of which is a hash bucket. You use the hash function to assign each symbol to one of these *n* buckets.

If your hash function is good, you will end up with very close to *N*/*n* symbols in each bucket. If *N* is a somewhat less than *n*², then you shouldn't have more than *n* different symbols in each bucket and you can process each bucket individually in the second pass to split it into separate symbol files.

In your case *N* is about 10,000, which is a lot less than 500².

Since the total size of the bucket files is the same as the size of the original file, you will end up reading all the data twice, which should be a good bit faster than reading it 20 times.